# PHP copy file from /folder/ to /subdomain/ (domain to subdomain)

Tags: php, permissions, dns, copy, subdomain

I want to copy a file from /folder to /subdomain using

```
copy($src,$dest);
```

However I get a Failed to open stream ...
When I check with

```
is_writable($dest_folder);
```

The subdomain folder is not writable.
The subdomain is created using the DirectAdmin api
So the folder has the owner of the domain and php has as owner Apache.

I think thats the problem, however I could not find to bypass this (chmod seems to not working or I am doing something wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full path and use chmod.

```
chmod($path.$file.".".$extension, 0777);
```

Otherwise the problem has to do with groups and chown.

```
chown($subdomain, $user_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, above aint working (not permitted). So have to look further :)